# CollectionView Xamarin grid view sizing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working with a collectionview using `GridItemsLayout` `orientation=“Vertical” Span=“2”`.
When I click on a button that expands the lower part of my grid item. Currently only by using `ItemSizingStrategy.MeasureAllItems` I am able to get the lower part to expand. I was wondering if there is a way of controlling the item positioning on the image so the images always align and only the lower half expands evenly.
I am aware each item has its own layout, but this looks messy. I’ve read the documentation mention this type of sizing.
<ContentPage.Content>

```
    <StackLayout>
       <CollectionView x:Name="CollectionList"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Shares}"
                       IsGrouped="True"
ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems">

           <!--HEADER-->
           <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Padding="5"
                                BackgroundColor="#f7f7fb">

                       <Label x:Name="labelname"
                              Text="{Binding GroupKey}"
                            />

                       <Button Text=" More"
                               FontSize="16"
                               Clicked="OpenButton_Clicked"/>
                      
                   </StackLayout>
               </DataTemplate>
           </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <!--TEMPLATING-->
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
           <!--BODY-->
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:ShareViewModel">
                <Grid Padding="5" Margin="1,0,1,0" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ImageButton x:Name="image"
                           Source="{Binding ImageLink}"
                           WidthRequest="150"
                           Clicked="FullImageView"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"/>
                    
                    <Label FontSize="16"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="0"/>

                     <Label x:Name="label_more"
                            Text="More"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>

                    <Label 
                           Text="{Binding CreateDate}"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="0"/>
```

```
                    <ImageButton IsVisible="{Binding TVNImageSet}"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.ToggleTVNCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=sharepage}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                Source="addresscard.png"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.Column="1">
                    </ImageButton>

                    <!--Lower Section if the card is tapped (EXPAND)-->
                    <StackLayout
                        IsVisible="{Binding TVNVisible}"
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                     IsVisible="{Binding PhoneVisible}"
                                     ClassId="{Binding Phone}">
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
                                                      NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                      />
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Image Source="call.png"
                                   WidthRequest="15"/>
                             <Label 
                               FontSize="12"
                               Text="{Binding Phone}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                         <Label 
                                FontSize="12"
                                Text="{Binding Address}"
                                IsVisible="{Binding  AddressVisible}">
                             <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                 <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                             </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                         </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

All `BindingContext.ToggleTVNCommand` does is set `TVNVisible` to true which shows the lower half the "expanding potion". I don't need to use collection view if there is an easier way fo displaying this data, but CollectionVView seemed like the best choice for the layout and item source I wanted.

[image]

Comment: please post the relevant code/xaml

Comment: have you tried setting the VerticalAignment of the image?

Comment: yes, nothing happens. The images are still all out of sync. I think this is because the image inside the grid being clicked isn't the problem. The problem is with the ones around it. Ideally when the TVN (card) is selected the entire row would be lifted not just the individual item. Just not sure how to accomplish this. @Jason

Comment: not sure if this can help, give ExpanderView a try
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander

Comment: *"yes, nothing happens."* - Did you set VerticalAlignment=Start on BOTH the top layout of each item (I think here it is Grid) AND on the image itself? On ALL items (not just the expanded one). BTW, to see what is going on within each item area, set different background colors at each level of the item - this will show you WHICH level of the hierarchy is failing to go to top (vertical start).

Comment: yes @ToolmakerSteve I tried that the whole color background change as well so I was not shooting in the dark. I ended up having other issues that were also contributing to the same issue. The list itself was just not working with my dynamic list of items/sizes. I ended up working with SyncFusion sfListView.. right off the bat it worked and my items were automatically lined just on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around GitHub forums on bugs and updates for Xamarin, someone mentioned to just work with SyncFusion's sfListview the membership is not that bad and my company is willing to pay for it if it makes working with Xamarin easier.
That wasn't the solution I was hoping for, but it works and their customer support is great.
below is the reference
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/listview/working-with-sflistview